# PHP Session handling trouble server

Tags: php, session

I am having some trouble with `session_start()`, I have 3 php files, the first is a form that posts the data:

```
<form method="post" action="startsession.php">
    First name: <input name="firstname" type="text" value="">
    <br>
    Last name: <input name="lastname" type="text" value="">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The second one called `startsession.php` starts the session and stores the data from the form and sends to an other page for the testing:

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
...
<?php
    $_SESSION['firstname'] = $_POST["firstname"];
    $_SESSION['lastname'] = $_POST["lastname"];
?>
<p><a href="sessiontest.php>"> Link </a></p>
```

Finally `sessiontest.php` just starts session and reads the stored variables, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    echo $_SESSION['firstname'];
?>
```

Can someone help me to figure out what might be the problem? Could it be something on the server? the rest of my PHP code works fine, the form posting also works fine and I can read the data from the `startsession.php` but not from `sessiontest.php.`

Comment: `<p><a href="sessiontest.php>"> Link </a></p>` doesn't look right or is it a typo ?

Comment: sorry I misstyped, but it is correct in code

Answer (score 1):

you have entered the wrong link in

```
<p><a href="sessiontest.php>"> Link </a></p>
```

since you added the `>` tag in `href="sessiontest.php>"` so please replace it with the following code

```
<p><a href="sessiontest.php"> Link </a></p>
```

Answer (score -1):

you write

"> Link

remove > sign in link

Link

it will work

Comment: You probably mean change "sessiontest.php>" to "sessiontest.php" (always formulate your answers as clearly as possible)